# Numpy output interpretation

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, video-processing

I'm a beginner at video processing using python.

I have a raw video data captured from a camera and I need to check whether the video has bright or dark frames in it.

So far what I have achieved is I can read the raw video using numpy in python. 
Below is my code.

```
import numpy as np 
fd = open('my_video_file.raw', 'rb') 
rows = 4800
cols = 6400 
f = np.fromfile(fd, dtype=np.uint8,count = rows*cols) 
im = f.reshape((rows,cols)) #notice row, column format 
print im 
fd.close()
```

Output :

```
[[ 81  82  58 ...,   0   0   0]  [  0   0   0 ...,   0   0   0] 
[  0  0   0 ...,   0   0   0]  ...,   [141 128 136 ...,   1   2   2] 
[ 40  39  35 ..., 192 192 192]  [190 190 190 ...,  74  60  60]]
```

Based on the array or numpy output , is it possible to check whether the raw video data has dark(less bright) frames or not.

Also please tell me what does the numpy output (print im) mean ?
If you have any links which I can refer to, its most welcome.

Comment: Fix your code please. The lines are converging.

Comment: How many channels your video frames have? Are they grayscale or color frames?

Comment: Based on the fact that 1) your code (and your output) obviously didn't come out of any interpreter, but probably crtl-v'd from a webpage and 2) you seem to have no idea even what to ask - I'd say you probably need to first read up on python, numpy, and [ask] before you ask any questions about video processing.  Just a hint to get you started - videos generally have length, width, and *time* - so you'll need to read in at least one more dimension

Comment: @Batyrkhan Saduanov , they are color frames...

Comment: @Daniel F, dont jump into the conclusion that the code was just a direct copy paste from the web . I had executed and confirmed the output before posting it here. I agree, I'm not that good in numpy and thats what I mentioned in the question , and thats why I'm seeking an answer. Also just because , u didn't understand the question doesn't mean , others are wrong. Next time when you use such harsh words, think twice.

Comment: You are asking about basic image-processing, but your video-read code looks very scary / wrong. Sadly there is not much to analyze because we don't have that data. I highly recommend checking your code first, e.g. by plotting out one frame using matplotlib.

Comment: @sascha, Yes .. I do understand your concern. I have been working on image processing using openCV . But in this case , unfortunately openCV doesn't support raw data. So , somehow I'm trying to make it using numpy with some work around. If you have any alternatives  , please suggest. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have colorfull frames with red, green and blue channels, i.e NxMx3 matrix then you can convert this matrix from RGB representation to HSV (Hue, Saturation, Value) representation which is also will be NxMx3 matrix. Then you can take Value page from this matrix, i.e. third channel of this matrix and calculate average of all elements in this matrix. Put any threshold like 0.5 and if average is less than this value then this frame can be considered as dark.

Read about HSV [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

To convert RGB vector to HSV vector you can use [matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv(arr)](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv) function.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little insight on your problem. (You might want to read up a little more on digital image representation, [e.g. here](http://pippin.gimp.org/image_processing/chap_dir.html)). The frames of your video are read in in `uint8` format, i.e. pixels are encoded with values ranging from 0 to 255.

In general, higher values represent brighter pixels. Depending on your video you can have colored or non-colored frames as mentioned by @Batyrkhan Saduanov. So what you want to do is define minimum and maximum levels to declare a frame as "dark" or "bright".

In case of a non-colored you can easily use the mean pixel values of each frame, an asign threshold levels as in:

[image: if]